# Как в bitrix не отображать элементы компонента(каталога) по произвольному условию?

Tags: битрикс

Есть каталог с разделами и элементами в них. В USER есть доп. поля, где можно отметить элементы/разделы, которые будут отображаться для данного USER'а. Но отображение происходит по IncludeComponent, и отображается весь каталог у всех юзеров. Так как не отображать не отмеченные в доп. поле юзера  разделы/компоненты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Покажите пожалуйста как у Вас происходит установка элементов для пользователя. 
Если вы используете для вывода компоненты (catalog, catalog.section, news.list) у них есть параметр FILTER_NAME http://prntscr.com/ohz3az. 
Например для  news.list если параметр FILTER_NAME = "arrFilter" то решение для вашей задачи будет следующее.

```php
<?
$arrID = "Ид элементов доступные пользователю"
global $arrFilter
$arrFilter["ID"] = $arrID;
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:news.list","",Array(
"FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter"
));
?>
```

Нужно еще сделать проверку на пустоту $arrID приравняв его к нулю в противном случае

Comment: Элементы выводятся правильно, но можно ли как то фильтровать разделы?

Comment: Какой компонент используется ?

Comment: Попробуйте "SECTION_ID"